# numpy: return boolean with true if array elements are in a given set

Tags: python, numpy

```
>>> s = {0, 4, 27}
>>> a = numpy.arange(10)
>>> t = some_func(a)
>>> t
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

What's the canonical `some_func` needed to be to make this work?

**What I've tried**

I've tried vectorizing a lambda function, which works ... it just doesn't feel like the right way to do this.

```
>>> f = lambda i: i in s
>>> vf = numpy.vectorize(f)
>>> t = numpy.fromfunction(vf, a.shape)
>>> t.astype(int)
array([1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Comment: I think what you want is in1d from numpy. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html#numpy.in1d

Comment: Dont' really do `numpy`, but would something like `[i in s for i in a]` work here?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) with `s` as a NumPy array

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> s = np.array([0, 4, 27])
>>> a = np.arange(10)
>>> t = np.in1d(a, s)
>>> t
array([ True, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be faster:

```
t = np.zeros(10, int)
sa = np.array(list(s))
t[sa[sa<10]] = 1
```

Unless of course, `a` is not `np.arange()`